# using setTitle on a method

Tags: java, swing

I need to set the title from a method (not constructor). I tried doing it like this, but it's not working:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class PointGraphWriter extends JPanel
{
   public String title;

   public void setTitle(String name)
   {
       title = name;
   }
   public PointGraphWriter()
   {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame;
       int width= 300;
       frame.setSize(width*3/2,width);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setTitle(title);
       frame.setBackground(Color.white);
       frame.getContentPane;
       frame.add(this);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
}
```

with the main method :

```
public class TestPlot
{
    public static void main(String[] a)
    { 
        PointGraphWriter e = new PointGraphWriter();
        e.setTitle("Graph of y = x*x");
    }
}
```

Comment: With `setTitle`, are you trying to change the `title` variable or the title of the frame?

Comment: @rgettman the title variable, and then the title of the frame with that variable.

Comment: rgettman's answer below is exactly correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You changed the variable `title` but that doesn't affect the frame.  You will need to call `setTitle` on the frame again.

Keep an instance variable for the frame:

```
private JFrame frame;
```

In the constructor, assign the new `JFrame` to the instance variable, so you can change its title later in `setTitle`:

```
public void setTitle(String name)
{
   title = name;
   frame.setTitle(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a method to alter the variable `title`, which is good. The problem you are having is that you are trying to set the title of the frame *in the constructor method*.

In this code:

```
PointGraphWriter e = new PointGraphWriter();
e.setTitle("Graph of y = x*x");
```

`e` is constructed *before* you use the `setTitle` method to change the `title` variable in the `PointGraphWriter` class. Therefore, you are trying to set the title of the frame to be a `null` String because the `setTitle`method is only called after the constructor method.

You could do two things:

1. Set the title of the frame in the `setTitle` method:

   ```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame;
   public void setTitle(String name)
   {
       frame.setTitle(name);
   }
   ```
2. Or you could change your constructor method to take in the title as an argument:

   ```
   public PointGraphWriter(String title)
   {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame;
       int width= 300;
       frame.setSize(width*3/2,width);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setTitle(title);
       frame.setBackground(Color.white);
       frame.getContentPane;
       frame.add(this);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
   ```

   And then create `PointGraphWriter` like this:

   ```
   PointGraphWriter e = new PointGraphWriter("Graph of y = x*x");
   ```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. It was actually the first option that i had to use. It's a school exercise and i had to do it that way (from the setTitle() method) but I didn't know that i can use the frame object in the setTitle() method that way too. Thanks very much!